# What does this relation definition mean and how is it even a partial order?

Tags: relations, order-theory

Im confused by this:
[image]

First of all, is it equivalent to this?
[image]

Second, how is that even a partial order? It's not reflexive, $(2,1)\in A$ but its not true that $(2,1)R(2,1)$

Also, what does the last sentence mean? What is a component element and is the natural order defined on the natural numbers a relation of some kind?

Comment: Your translation is correct. It's a [strict partial order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Strict_partial_orders) (suggested by the choice of symbol $<$ instead of $\le$), so it's not reflexive. The natural order relation on the natural numbers is the standard one from basic arithmetic; you're told to use this relation to interpret expressions like "$x_1>x_2$". A component element is an entry in a tuple.

Comment: The natural or usual order of $\mathbb{N}$ is just the strict linear order defined by the usual interpretation of $\lt$. So basically the relation that gives us $1\lt 2 \lt 3\dots$, etc.